# Configure Task titles in SPD Custom Task Process

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I'm in the process of creating a SharePoint Designer approval process, based on the OOTB Approval workflow.

One of the customizations required is for the titles of tasks generated by the workflow to fit a certain structure.  I'm able to modify the title of the Approval tasks ("Please approve...") style tasks without issue, but I would also like to be able to alter the Change Request tasks title ("A change request...") but I can't seem to find any property to configure this.

Am I missing an obvious parameter somewhere? Is there a simple way to accomplish this without resorting to nasty string compares?

I'm using SharePoint 2010 if that makes any difference?

Comment: I have the very same situation. Did you ever find a solution to this? (My apologies if I'm posting this question in a section dedicated to Answers) Thanks a million,
Ben

Comment: @BenLenihan Unfortunately no, we ended up just living with the behaviour.

Comment: Any news on an answer to this?  Neil, it's been a long time since you posted, but we have the same problem and are looking for an answer.